# 3d image visualisation with numpy/vtk

Tags: python, 3d, visualization

I'm trying to display further images (ct-scan) using numpy/vtk as describe in this sample code (http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/vtkWithNumpy) but I don't get it and don't know why. 
If someone could help me it would be kind.

Here's my code :

```
import vtk
import numpy as np
import os
import cv, cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
import Image

DEBUG =True
directory="splitted_mri/"
w = 226
h = 186
d = 27
stack = np.zeros((w,d,h))

k=-1 #add the next picture in a differente level of depth/z-positions
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    k+=1
    img = directory + file
    im = Image.open(img)
    temp = np.asarray(im, dtype=int)
    stack[:,k,:]= temp
print stack.shape

#~ plt.imshow(test)
#~ plt.show()

print type(stack[10,10,15])

res = np.amax(stack)
res1 = np.amin(stack)
print res, type(res)
print res1, type(res1)

#~ for (x,y,z), value in np.ndenumerate(stack):
    #~ stack[x,y,z]=np.require(stack[x,y,z],dtype=np.int16)
    #~ print type(stack[x,y,z])

stack = np.require(stack,dtype=np.uint16)
print stack.dtype


if DEBUG : print stack.shape
dataImporter = vtk.vtkImageImport()
data_string = stack.tostring()

dataImporter.CopyImportVoidPointer(data_string, len(data_string))
dataImporter.SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar()
dataImporter.SetNumberOfScalarComponents(1)
dataImporter.SetDataExtent(0, w-1, 0, 1, 0, h-1)
dataImporter.SetWholeExtent(0, w-1, 0, 1, 0, h-1)
essai = raw_input()
alphaChannelFunc = vtk.vtkPiecewiseFunction()
colorFunc = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
for i in range (0,255):
    alphaChannelFunc.AddPoint(i, 0.9)
    colorFunc.AddRGBPoint(i,i,i,i)

volumeProperty = vtk.vtkVolumeProperty()
volumeProperty.SetColor(colorFunc)
#volumeProperty.ShadeOn()
volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(alphaChannelFunc)

# This class describes how the volume is rendered (through ray tracing).
compositeFunction = vtk.vtkVolumeRayCastCompositeFunction()
# We can finally create our volume. We also have to specify the data for it, as well as how the data will be rendered.
volumeMapper = vtk.vtkVolumeRayCastMapper()
volumeMapper.SetVolumeRayCastFunction(compositeFunction)
volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(dataImporter.GetOutputPort())

# The class vtkVolume is used to pair the preaviusly declared volume as well as the properties to be used when rendering that volume.
volume = vtk.vtkVolume()
volume.SetMapper(volumeMapper)
volume.SetProperty(volumeProperty)

# With almost everything else ready, its time to initialize the renderer and window, as well as creating a method for exiting the application
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWin.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWin)

# We add the volume to the renderer ...
renderer.AddVolume(volume)
# ... set background color to white ...
renderer.SetBackground(1, 1, 1)
# ... and set window size.
renderWin.SetSize(400, 400)

# A simple function to be called when the user decides to quit the application.
def exitCheck(obj, event):
    if obj.GetEventPending() != 0:
        obj.SetAbortRender(1)

# Tell the application to use the function as an exit check.
renderWin.AddObserver("AbortCheckEvent", exitCheck)

#to quit, press q
renderInteractor.Initialize()
# Because nothing will be rendered without any input, we order the first render manually before control is handed over to the main-loop.
renderWin.Render()
renderInteractor.Start()
```

Comment: What's the error/problem?

Comment: It's hard to guess where you're having problems as we do not have your data to try it ourselves. Please provide more details.

Comment: The question is unclear as it does not state what the problem is and includes a large code sample rather than a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally find out what was wrong
here's my new code

```
import vtk
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
import Image

DEBUG =False
directory="splitted_mri/"

l = []

k=0 #add the next picture in a differente level of depth/z-positions
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    img = directory + file
    if DEBUG : print img
    l.append(img)
# the os.listdir function do not give the files in the right order 
#so we need to sort them
l=sorted(l)

temp = Image.open(l[0])
h, w = temp.size
d = len(l)*5 #with our sample each images will be displayed 5times to get a better view
if DEBUG : print 'width, height, depth : ',w,h,d

stack = np.zeros((w,d,h),dtype=np.uint8)

for i in l:
    im = Image.open(i)
    temp = np.asarray(im, dtype=int)
    for i in range(5):
        stack[:,k+i,:]= temp
    k+=5
    #~ stack[:,k,:]= temp
    #~ k+=1

if DEBUG :
    res = np.amax(stack)
    print 'max value',res
    res1 = np.amin(stack)
print 'min value',res1

#convert the stack in the right dtype
stack = np.require(stack,dtype=np.uint8)

if DEBUG :#check if the image have not been modified
test = stack [:,0,:]
plt.imshow(test,cmap='gray')
plt.show()

if DEBUG : print 'stack shape & dtype' ,stack.shape,',',stack.dtype

dataImporter = vtk.vtkImageImport()
data_string = stack.tostring()

dataImporter.CopyImportVoidPointer(data_string, len(data_string))
dataImporter.SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar()
dataImporter.SetNumberOfScalarComponents(1)

#vtk uses an array in the order : height, depth, width which is 
#different of numpy (w,h,d) 
w, d, h = stack.shape
dataImporter.SetDataExtent(0, h-1, 0, d-1, 0, w-1)
dataImporter.SetWholeExtent(0, h-1, 0, d-1, 0, w-1)

alphaChannelFunc = vtk.vtkPiecewiseFunction()
colorFunc = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
for i in range(256):
    alphaChannelFunc.AddPoint(i, 0.2)
    colorFunc.AddRGBPoint(i,i/255.0,i/255.0,i/255.0)
# for our test sample, we set the black opacity to 0 (transparent) so as
#to see the sample  
alphaChannelFunc.AddPoint(0, 0.0)
colorFunc.AddRGBPoint(0,0,0,0)

volumeProperty = vtk.vtkVolumeProperty()
volumeProperty.SetColor(colorFunc)
#volumeProperty.ShadeOn()
volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(alphaChannelFunc)

# This class describes how the volume is rendered (through ray tracing).
compositeFunction = vtk.vtkVolumeRayCastCompositeFunction()
# We can finally create our volume. We also have to specify the data for
# it, as well as how the data will be rendered.
volumeMapper = vtk.vtkVolumeRayCastMapper()
# function to reduce the spacing between each image
volumeMapper.SetMaximumImageSampleDistance(0.01)

volumeMapper.SetVolumeRayCastFunction(compositeFunction)
volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(dataImporter.GetOutputPort())

# The class vtkVolume is used to pair the preaviusly declared volume as 
#well as the properties to be used when rendering that volume.
volume = vtk.vtkVolume()
volume.SetMapper(volumeMapper)
volume.SetProperty(volumeProperty)

# With almost everything else ready, its time to initialize the renderer and window,
# as well as creating a method for exiting the application
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWin.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWin)

# We add the volume to the renderer ...
renderer.AddVolume(volume)
# ... set background color to white ...
renderer.SetBackground(1, 1, 1)
# ... and set window size.
renderWin.SetSize(550, 550)
renderWin.SetMultiSamples(4)
# A simple function to be called when the user decides to quit the application.
def exitCheck(obj, event):
    if obj.GetEventPending() != 0:
        obj.SetAbortRender(1)

# Tell the application to use the function as an exit check.
renderWin.AddObserver("AbortCheckEvent", exitCheck)

#to auit, press q
renderInteractor.Initialize()
# Because nothing will be rendered without any input, we order the first
# render manually before control is handed over to the main-loop.
renderWin.Render()
renderInteractor.Start()
```

Comment: This answer is unclear as it does not explain what the solution was but instead includes are large code sample which is very similar to that in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a solution not using VTK, you could use Matplotlib imshow and interactive navigation with keys.

This tutorial shows how:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/matplotlib-3d-volumetric-data
https://github.com/jni/mpl-volume-viewer

and here an implementation for viewing RTdose files:
https://github.com/pydicom/contrib-pydicom/pull/19

See also:
https://github.com/napari/napari